# SN74HC138 demultiplexer. How do I implement a switch?

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, output

I have this [demultiplexer](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc138.pdf) and I need to configure it in such a way that I can control 8 transistors using its outputs. They NEED to be NPN transistors, so when I select an output using the addresses, it must give me logic level 1, not 0. The problem is, in the data sheet of this multiplexer there is a logic table and according to it there doesn't seem to be any possibility of getting a HIGH logic level at the selected output, and only LOW logic levels at the other, not selected, outputs. Is there a way I can do that using this demux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a second NPN as an inverter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh5TPv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Adjust resistor values and add speed-up caps and/or Schottky clamps to meet your speed and current requirements.

Comment: Or a set of 8 inverters or "inverting drivers": eg http://www.instructables.com/id/Running-LEDs-With-555-74163-74138-And-74240/step4/74138-3to8-Decoder-With-74240-Inverterdriver/

Comment: That is probably the better solution, since the NPN requirement was there, I went with the assumption there were a lot available.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Use a 74HC238 instead, which does what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, but I was thinking if I could somehow do it with this one, because my electronics shop doesn't have any other one in stock.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 74HC238 instead. Its got active-high outputs instead of the '138's active-lows.